# How do I use Count Aggregation in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a SQL thing where I change a column to the count of its values in Python.

Like

```
A Blue
B Red
C Blue
```

Would be replaced with

```
Blue 2
Red 1
```

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below with your column names. Try using this as example

```
    import pandas as pd
    mydata=[['A','Blue'],['B','Red'],['C','Blue']]
    df= pd.DataFrame(mydata,columns=['var','color'])
    x=df.groupby(by=['color'])['var'].count()
    print(x)
```